# Why are my POST variables showing up on URL string?

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, post

I've implemented an ajax post function based on a button click.  The code is

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/phpscripts?action=manage",
    data: {location: loc, lat: latitude, lon: longitude, heading: head, filename: file},
    success: function(){
      $("#panoInfo").html("<div id='message'></div>");
      $("#message").html("Valid Submission");
  }
});
```

I specified the POST method since I don't want the variables to be visible via the URL.  However, they are.

My test URL before posting is

```
http://localhost/JMCTour/buildtour.php
```

Afterwards

```
http://localhost/JMCTour/buildtour.php?filename=1-prefix_blended_fused.jpg&location=Start+of+Tour&lat=43.682211&long=-70.450705&heading=100&submit=Save
```

Why?

Comment: Seems like your not handling the submit button correctly and sending all the data via get. Could you post the submit code?

Comment: You could use `$.post()` instead...

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs He is using `$.post()`, only it's the non-shortcut version. See `type: "POST"`

Comment: @KevinB, it may do the same thing, but it's not `$.post()`.  We could argue semantics about what's under the hood, but IMHO if it's always going to be a POST operation, being explicit is a good thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs for jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (emphasis mine):

> **data**
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. **See processData option to prevent this automatic processing.** Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

and therefore:

> **processDataBoolean**
>
> Default: true
>
> By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.

Comment: I missed that part. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 9):

Make sure your form tag has `method='POST'`

```
<form method='POST'>
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm making quite a few assumptions here due to lack of information in the question.

More than likely your form looks something like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="lon" />
    <input type="text" name="lat" />
    <input type="text" name="heading" />
    <input type="file" name="image" />

    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Immediately we have a problem, your file input. Files cannot be sent via ajax using jQuery's ajax methods without including additional plugins that correctly handle it behind the scenes or writing your code to instead submit to a hidden iframe or some other method(html5?flash?).

Ignoring the file input, here's where your original problem is.

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax(...);
});
```

I left out the ajax options because they are irrelevant. The problem is that since the button in your form is the last input in the form and there isn't a submit button, it will act like a submit button and submit the form unless you prevent that default action. If you do not prevent that default action, the form will be submitted with the default type of "GET" since you didn't set a type in your form.

To prevent the default action of the click event, either return false, or use `event.preventDefault()`

```
$("#submit").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax(...);
});
```

Fixing the file input problem is probably already answered in several other SO questions.

Comment: You are almost correct, except I'm not sending a file itself via the query, just the relative location.  I know its a bit of a holy war in database design regarding storing files themselves or links to in a database.  I'm going for option 2 in this instance.